# How to store generated CSV with JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, file, download

I have this code to generate and download a CSV file. I need to store that generated CSV file on the server. How I can do that?

```js
var csv = 'Email Address,First Name,Last Name\n';

for (var i = 0; i < formDatas.length; i++) {
  csv += formDatas[i][0].email + ",";
  csv += formDatas[i][0].first_name + ",";
  csv += formDatas[i][0].last_name + ",";
  csv += "\n";
  //console.log(formDatas[i][0]);
}

//document.write(csv);
var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';

//provide the name for the CSV file to be downloaded
hiddenElement.download = 'Famous Personalities.csv';
hiddenElement.click();
```

Comment: Send the generated CSV file to the server using AJAX, and at the server side upload the received CSV file based on the programming language you are using.

Comment: How I can do that from this code?